# How to pass a variable via stdin to a cli command programmatically?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, graphql

I'm using [graphql-schema-linter](https://github.com/cjoudrey/graphql-schema-linter) package to validate a GraphQL schema.

I wonder if it's possible to perform validation programmatically by passing type definitions to stdin like this or not...

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const typeDefs = require('./type-defs');
exec(`graphql-schema-linter --stdin "${typeDefs}"`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) console.log('ERROR: ', err);
    if (stdout) console.log('STDOUT: ', stdout);
    if (stderr) console.log('STDERR: ', stderr);    
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs
});
```

The following code produces an error because I'm not quite sure how to pass type defs via stdin the right way

Comment: Can you print the command that's trying to execute and run it externally?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some digging I found the solution. Turned out I had to use `spawnSync` that would accept an stdin as input

```
const command = spawnSync('graphql-schema-linter', ['-s'], { input: typeDefs, encoding: 'utf-8' });
```